# How to freeze packages installed only in the virtual environment?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper, virtual-environment

How to freeze packages installed only in the virtual environment, that is, without the global ones?

Answer (score 116, accepted):

You need to use the `-l` or `--local` option to freeze only the local packages (and not the global ones)

```
pip freeze -l > requirements.txt
```

Make sure you are working in the `virtualenv` before doing `pip freeze -l`.

Comment: For me this worked (or use `python` for older versions):
`python3 -m pip freeze -l > requirements.txt`

Answer (score 11):

Only local packages on virtual environment

```
pip freeze -l > requirements.txt # or --local instead of -l
```

Only local packages installed by the user on virtual environment

```
pip freeze --user > requirements.txt
```

---

See the documentation for further details: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_freeze/.

Answer (score 7):

For me (macOS) the following worked

```
path/to/venv/bin/pip3 freeze -l
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm on Windows 10, python 3.6, with my virtual environment called **env** activated using command prompt I found that `pip freeze -l` does not work (error), `python -m pip freeze -l` does not work (gets global packages) but changing into my virtual environment Scripts directory and running `pip freeze` or `pip freeze -l` works. Here is an example of this solution/work-around with my virtual environment, **env**:

```
cd \env\Scripts
pip freeze > ..\..\requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

I did try everything, even i inside venv it not worked. This code worked for me. It shows only pip packages in venv.

```
venv\Scripts\python.exe venv\Scripts\pip.exe freeze > requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
python venv/Path_to/bin/pip freeze -l
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the following command:

```
pip -E /path/to/env/ freeze
```

Comment: I think the `-E` parameter is use _inside_ the requirements.txt file to show a version control project address

Comment: They are different "-E" params: this one is command line params that says pip to do inside the given virtualenv

Comment: Could you possible point me to documentation for this? Does it only freeze the specified virtuelenv even with global site packages enabled?

Comment: Run "pip help" and see "Options" section.

Comment: `$ pip -E venv/ freeze
Usage: pip COMMAND [OPTIONS]

pip: error: no such option: -E`

Answer (score -2):

Install whatever you need to freeze in your virtual environment, and then

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

After that install the packages in the virtual environment that you do not want to freeze.