# Pip freeze --local

Tags: python, django

I am following a video tutorial and that guy did this:

```
$ pip freeze --local > requirement.txt
$ cat requirement.txt
```

this is to export all these packages with their versions in another project, but how:

- what is `pip freeze`? and
- what is that `requirement.txt`? are we supposed to export all those packages in a txt file, how can .txt file do that does it grab their name?
- what is the word `cat` in second line? my machine can't understand either of those, but in his computer they were working, my machine says:

  [image]

  As you can see `cat` is not recognized.

Then I look in virtualenv directory to search for requirement.txt and I find this

[image]

Yes, `requirement.txt` is zero bytes, nothing in it.
What is the problem?

Next I googled for what is `pip freeze` and what is `cat`? I couldn't find a simple definition for cat. but here is `pip freeze`

> Usage : pip freeze [options] 
>   Description Output installed packages in
>   requirements format.
>
> packages are listed in a case-insensitive sorted order.

What is "requirements format"? Is that a text file?

Then I came to this question in Stack Overflow: [How to freeze packages installed only in the virtual environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073097/how-to-freeze-packages-installed-only-in-the-virtual-environment)

Does he means how do I preserve packages with a layer of ice in my virtual environment?

Comment: `cat` is a Linux command: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cat.1.html

Comment: You might find the [Django Girls tutorial](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/) useful. It gives Windows versions of the commands, and explains the reasons for lots of steps so hopefully you won't get sidetracked too much.

Comment: None of that has anything to do with Python or Django - `pip freeze` dumps a list of your Python packages into the file you specify, you will need this when deploying a project but it's pointless before you even start developing. `cat` just outputs the contents of the file to the terminal, and this command only works on Unix-based systems (eg Linux), not Windows. If you're completely new to Python I would advise to learn the basics of the language first, including using `pip` and virtual environments, then learn Django when you're comfortable with Python.

Comment: All the information you are asking for is very easy to find by simple google searches. There is extensive documentation for all those tools. I doubt you have spend enough time to try and find the answers to your questions on your own.

Comment: Thank you everyone! Looks like I have to do a full 10 hours search before asking any question in here.

Comment: is something wrong with this question? why the downvotes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pip is a package manger for Python modules. The command `pip freeze` outputs all installed modules (including version numbers). The `--local` flag prevents Pip from printing globally installed packages in a virtual environment.

Usually, a Python program depends on other modules. You can put those *required* modules in a text file (`requirements.txt` by convention) so that other people can install those dependencies by running `pip install -r requirements.txt`. You can conveniently create such a file using `pip freeze`.

On a Linux machine, `cat` is used to output the contents of a file. You can use `type` on Windows.

The *requirements format* looks like this:

```
docutils==0.11
Jinja2==2.7.2
MarkupSafe==0.19
Pygments==1.6
Sphinx==1.2.2
```

Each lines consist of a python module name and a corresponding version.

---

https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_freeze/
https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/1.1/requirements.html

Comment: Thank you so much. Understanding requirement.txt helped me figure out what is going on in here !

Answer (score 0):

Working: cat requirements.txt
's' - at the end...